# How to configure DHCP for a wifi access point in front of a DSL router

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dhcp, dsl

What's the general procedure for adding a wifi access point to a DSL modem connection. That is, I've got

```
DSL router -> Desktop computer
```

and I want to get to

```
DSL router -> Wireless router -> Desktop computer & Laptops via wifi
```

If it matters, equipment is:

- Wireless router: Netgear WGR614
- DSL router: Speedstream 5100

Right now I've got the DSL router with local IP 192.168.0.1/24, the wireless with 192.168.0.100, but I'm having trouble with DHCP. Which router is supposed to assign the addresses? If I give clients a static IP in the range all works - otherwise somebody grabs the remote IP and no one else can connect to the internet.

Maybe I'm supposed to use the Netgear to replace the Speedstream entirely but I couldn't get that to work.

Should the Netgear be on a different subnet entirely or something?

Answer (score 1):

I regually set this sort of thing up. What you basically want to do is see if your wireless router supports standard "access point" mode. Failing this, try disabling NAT and DHCP which basically does the same thing.

After you have done this, just plug one RJ45/ethernet cable in to your current router and then it should provide wireless access to the network.

That being said, I would personally use the Netgear as your main router. Make sure you have copied ALL settings from all tabs such as Multiplexing Method, VCI, VPI along with all your account settings.

If you cannot find this, try Googling your ISP's name and the router and see if anyone else has reported what settings you need. Lastly, failing this, ring up your IP and ask for the settings.

Comment: Don't forget that you must not use the Internet/WAN port on the wireless router. It's not connected to the WAN, only the LAN.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but the best solution is to put the DSL modem in bridge mode. This allows the router to get the external IP address and do its thing. [Here's a guide](http://www.dslreports.com/faq/8722) on how to put your modem in bridge mode:

> 1. In your web browser browse to »192.168.0.1 This address will be located on a yellow sticker on the bottom of your modem.
> 2. The first screen will ask you for your Modem Access Code. This also will be located on the same yellow sticker.
> 3. Select Advanced from the blue buttons on the left.
> 4. Click the PPP locations button.
> 5. The modem may ask your for the Modem Access Code again. If so type it in again and click continue.
> 6. Select the radio button labeled, "Bridged Mode (PPPoE is not used)"
> 7. Click Save Changes.
> 8. A "PPP Location Warning" page will come up. Click "Change PPP Location."
> 9. A "Restart Needed" page will come up. Click "Restart"
> 10. Reboot your computer and router (if applicable.) You will now need some form of PPPoE software on your computer or a router that supports
>       PPPoE. Be warned that even if you are using Enternet 300 or XP/OSX's
>       built in PPPoE SBC tech support will not troubleshoot connectivity
>       issues until you have put your modem back in PPPoE on board mode.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off DHCP on the wireless router, and give the wireless router a static IP address OUTSIDE the range of IP addresses that the Speedstream is handing out. Connect the two routers from LAN port to LAN port.